# Titanium Appcelerator Android Module Development Android NDK path

Tags: android, module, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to integrate a titanium module project into my native application. For that I am trying to develop a module project in titanium studio. But during building module I am getting the following errors, even after manually written path to Android NDK in build.properties file:

"The following error occurred while executing this line:
   exec returned: 2"

I tried all the possible solutions that are available, can any one share any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you download and install the NDK? and set the path?

Comment: Yes i already downloaded and set path now it's working fine,thanx